# Need to execute FTP commands from batch script

Tags: command-line, command, batch-file

> Need to write batch script which copies file from FTP to local drive

I'm trying to achieve this using `cmd` command prompt

inside batch file

please help me or paste any thread.

I found the answer thanks a lot but,

I need to use 2files `script.txt` and `batch.bat`

which contains script.txt code:

```
open ftp.server.com
username
password
cd folderpath/newfolder
get file1.xml
close
bye
```

and batch.bat code

```
ftp -v -i -s:script.txt
echo done!
```

> But How can i do it using only `.bat` file so that I need only 1 file not 2 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point:

> 1. Perform a NSLOOKUP for the FTP site, e.g. nslookup ftp.microsoft.com make a note of the IP address
> 2. Edit the LMHOSTS file (in %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc)
> 3. Add line  MicrosoftFTP #PRE e.g. 207.46.133.140 MicrosoftFTP #PRE
> 4. Save the file
> 5. Open a CMD.EXE session. Enter command: nbtstat -R This purges and reloads the name table cache
> 6. Type command: net view \MicrosoftFTP You should see information on the site
> 7. Now map a drive (to share data) net use * \MicrosoftFTP\data /user:anonymous
> 8. All done. It will pass a drive letter for the connection

The next step would be to make steps 1-4 automatic by scripting the commands and using file/[string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) to update the hosts file if necessary.

With a drive mapped you can then presumably do a normal Xcopy from one drive to another.

Reference: 
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080612073002AAruBR0

***UPDATE*** In response to your edit:

In your main batch.bat file, dynamically create script.txt as follows:

```
@echo off 
@echo open ftp.server.com > script.txt
@echo username >> script.txt
@echo password >> script.txt
@echo cd folderpath/newfolder >> script.txt
@echo get file1.xml >> script.txt
@echo close >> script.txt
@echo bye >> script.txt
```

Then do

```
ftp -v -i -s:script.txt
```

Finally - to tidy-up, remove the temporary script.txt:

```
del script.txt
```

Comment: thanks a ton! but how can i do it in only .bat file i mean using only one file :)

Comment: Perfect, just need to lose any spaces preceding ">" otherwise the username and password will get an undesired extra space and the script fails.